# Regex fails in str_replace_all function?

Tags: r, regex, string, stringr

I am trying to generate a regular expression that will find:

`\"}}{\"risk_level` string and replace with
`\"}},{\"risk_level`.

I have tried to do this with:

```
pattern = "\\\"\}\}\{\\\"risk_level"
replacement = "\\\"\}\}\,\{\\\"risk_level"
```

I am trying to do this in R str_replace_all() function.

It fails with the error:

> Error in stri_replace_all_regex(string, pattern,
>   fix_replacement(replacement),  :    Syntax error in regexp pattern.
>   (U_REGEX_RULE_SYNTAX)

Please advise.

Here is a toy example with example string:

```
x <- "\"simOperator\":\"42507\",\"simOperatorName\":\"333333333fdvdv\",\"groupIdentifierLevel1\":\"39ffffff\",\"networkType\":\"e43\",\"phoneCount\":\"1\",\"networkOperatorName\":\"Hfffff\"}}{\"risk_level\":\"HIGH\",\"average\":0.625,\"keys\":{\"checkpoint\":\"TRANSACTION\",\"requestId\":\"wfwfwfwfwf8eb-wfewefwewe91-abdd83164a99\"

str_replace_all(x, pattern = pattern, replacement = replacement)
```

Comment: Could you add the full code used?

Comment: @NelsonGon I have provided the sample string.

Comment: Why use regex? Use `gsub('"}}{"risk_level"', '"}},{"risk_level"', x, fixed=TRUE)`. Note your `x` string has no backslashes.

Comment: Your example `x` results in an error. You have to escape backslashes!

Comment: There are several typos here: 1) Your string has no backslashes, and you tried to introduce them into the regex pattern. You should not have tried that and you would not have posted this question. 2) In an ICU regex pattern, `{` must be escaped when outside a character class, you did not escape it properly - hence the error you see. 3) Your `x` is not quoted properly, the snippet errors out. If you are replacing fixed values, do not use regex, use `fixed(string_here)` in `str_replace` or `fixed=TRUE` in `sub`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for the answer please post as an answer. There is no reason to down vote. We all learn from each other!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
gsub("([}])([{])","\\1,\\2",string,perl=TRUE)
[1] "\"}},{\"risk_level"
```

Comment: Why two `}}` in the character class? `[}}]` = `[}]` = `}`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I just thought matching two that way would help.

Comment: Two `}`s are `}}`. Not `[}}]`. Check https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Comment: @SteveS I've not yet looked at `str_replace`. Perhaps escaping. Let me take a look.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm using `[]` to include the `}}`.

Comment: Well, if we follow your logic, I'd suggest `gsub("}{","},{",x,fixed=TRUE)`. Again, why regex?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Why it didn't work with str_replace? Because it lacks the perl = TRUE?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you can provide an answer btw. There's not a single way to solve a problem.

Comment: Why down voting?